# MySQL query to match similar words/sentences

Tags: python, mysql, search, full-text-search

I have a table in a MySQL Database which has this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `papers` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
`booktitle` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
`journal` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FULLTEXT KEY `title_fulltext` (`title`),
FULLTEXT KEY `booktitle_fulltext` (`booktitle`),
FULLTEXT KEY `journal_fulltext` (`journal`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1601769 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

Now I know that in the column title, somewhere within the millions of rows, there is a row which contains the string

```
nFOIL: Integrating Naïve Bayes and FOIL.
```

I want to look for

```
my_string = "nFOIL: integrating Naïve Bayes and FOIL"
```

and find the right row. You see it has to be a case insensitive search and the dot at the end is missing in the query. How do I implement this?

I tried

```
SELECT id FROM papers WHERE UPPER(title) LIKE %s
```

and converted my_string to upper case in python and put a "%" at the end of my_string but this doesn't seam a good way of handling this. It did not work too. =)

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have added FULLTEXT indexes, I though you already knew about MATCH AGAINST syntax of MySQL.

You should try

```
SELECT id FROM papers 
WHERE MATCH (title,booktitle,journal) AGAINST ('nFOIL: integrating Naïve Bayes and FOIL' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE WITH QUERY EXPANSION);
```

Comment: +1. I didn't know about "WITH QUERY EXPANSION". I'm just reading the manual. :)

Comment: I tried that. It turns out, that the query get's me a lot of results. The result I want is in the third place of all results. If I let this part of the query away "WITH QUERY EXPANSION" there are many results too but the one I wish for is in the first row of the results. What is the difference?

Comment: Read more about WITH QUERY EXPANSION on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html

Comment: Thank you very much. That got me in the right path. I solved my problem this way: `SELECT id, title, MATCH (title) AGAINST
('nFOIL: integrating Naïve Bayes and FOIL') AS score
FROM pubmap.papers WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST
('nFOIL: integrating Naïve Bayes and FOIL');`

Comment: Thanks. I had already found that page searching on google. Very interesting. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your collate in utf8_general_ci.
In this way your searches will be case insensitive.

Comment: Is it possible to change the collation of existing data?

Comment: It's always a good idea to make a backup before altering db/table structure. In your case yes. However, before you change anything, try to follow Pentium10 advices.